# postgresql: make objects owned by parent role

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a set of apps that produce data. Each app has its own credentials to access the DB, and they all inherit from a common role (`producer`).

I'd like to set default privileges to grant access to objects created by a `producer`, but it does not work because objects are owned by each particular app's login, not by `producer`.

So: is there a way to have all tables created by these apps to be owned by `producer` not by their particular login ? Or, is there a way to write these default privileges differently ?

EDIT: and I'd like to avoid changing all apps to make them do a SET ROLE...

EDIT2: and... I'm not the only one: [Automatically invoke `SET ROLE` when connecting to PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215549/automatically-invoke-set-role-when-connecting-to-postgresql), [Inherit default privileges: every table created by *any member of* role A is readable by role B](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249237/inherit-default-privileges-every-table-created-by-any-member-of-role-a-is-rea)

Answer (score 1):

No postgresql does not inherit permissions in this fashion,  Pretty much anything using the Create command sets the owner to the users that created it.

Use the [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-grant.html) command

Or after creating the tables set the Owner with [Alter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altertable.html)  command

```
Create table Mytable (list of columns);
Alter table Mytable  owner to producer;
```

Comment: Found this, to set ownership automatically https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/

Comment: @mathieu I would not use DDL trigger,  as it significantly alters PostgreSQL behavior, and means all the create tables get assigned this owner.  Also I do not think this has taken into account Schema changes with a user having access to schema yet the role does not have permissions.